# Is there a container style for view that wraps the renderItems component in React-native SectionList?

Tags: react-native

As far as I know,
there is only `contentContainerStyle` and `style` prop for container styling in SectionList,
which is both applied to all the contents inside the SectionList.

I would like to apply some styling to the container that wraps all the `renderItem` component only, and not other components like `renderSectionHeader` or `renderSectionFooter`. I can't seem to find any props for styling it.

Basically, I would like to apply some shadows to some view that wraps the renderItems for each section, not the individual items.

Any ways I can achieve this?

[image]

I want to apply styling to the red container.

Thanks!

Comment: can you not just wrap them all in a div the use css?

Comment: it's a little different for section list in react-native. I have to provide section list a 'renderItem' prop which is the component for each item, and it automatically renders the items. Not much I can do

Comment: How did you finally manage this problem? I'm looking for the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You can style to the renderItem's view. Wrap the render item in a  and style this view.

Comment: If I style renderItem, then it is applied to all the items. For example if I apply shadow, then shadow is applied to all the items in the section list, which is not what I want

Comment: You can add styles conditionally to the renter items. For example, if the 3rd item need a shadow, you can check the index and add the shadow style to the item with the index 2.